# n3290 : Elaborated type specifiers syntax changed?

Tags: c++, c++11

point From 2003 C++03 Document :

Elaborated type specifiers :section 3.4.4, para 1:

```
     "An elaborated-type-specifier  may be used to refer to  a
      previously declared class-name or enum-name even  though
      the name has been hidden by a non-type declaration.  **The
      class-name or enum-name in the elaborated-type-specifier
      may either be a simple identifier or be a qualified-id.**"
```

But in **n3290 Draft** they changed the **Elaborated type specifiers** (7.1.6.3)

7.1.6.3: Elaborated type specifiers

```
 elaborated-type-specifier:
     class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt nested-name-specifieropt identifier
     class-key nested-name-specifieropt templateopt simple-template-id
     enum nested-name-specifieropt identifier
```

May i know

1) what is the problem with earlier Syntax which supports typename c++03

```
     7.1.5.3 Elaborated type specifiers

 elaborated-type-specifier:
      class-key ::opt nested-name-specifieropt identifier
      class-key ::opt nested-name-specifieropt templateopt template-id
      enum ::opt nested-name-specifieropt identifier
      typename ::opt nested-name-specifier identifier
      typename ::opt nested-name-specifier templateopt template-id
```

2) IS that really compiler is following/not folling this rule...(which compiler supports this change )

3) When coming to the above point   3.4.4/1st

```
      The class-name or enum-name in the elaborated-type-specifier
      may either be a simple identifier or be a qualified-id
```

why it is not allowed in c++0x.

Please  any one explain this ?
Please  any one explain this ?

(When iam trying to add c++0x TAG it is not ..tagging ..please any one ..Add c++0x tag ? )

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a simple reorganization. `typename-specifier` is now not a kind of `elaborated-type-specifier`, but they are both kinds of `trailing-type-specifier`.
2. It's not clear what the compilers should do. Can you think of valid C++03 code that is not a valid C++0x?
3. What exactly is not allowed in C++0x? The grammar says a qualified-id is allowed there, as `nested-name-specifier_opt identifier`.